# Legend title in plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

How do I specify title for legend in `plotly`? I have a stacked bar graph that plots different durations like 0-10, 11-20. I want the legend title to say 'Duration'.

Comment: you provide a reproducible example

Comment: Yes, post a fiddle or code pen. It helps people play around with your particular use case.

Comment: @MLavoie like this picture: http://i1.wp.com/dacrook.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Top10MiamiBookings.png The title is "Charge".

Answer (score 17):

The simplest way to specify a legend title is to set it via `ggplot` and have `plotly` read it from the corresponding object:

```
library( plotly )

gg <- ggplot( mtcars, aes( x=mpg, y=wt, color=factor(vs) ) ) +
  geom_point() + labs( color = "MyTitle" )
ggplotly( gg )
```

However, the problem is that `plotly` converts the legend title into an annotation, which becomes disconnected from the legend in the process. In my browser, it also overlaps with the `plotly` menus in the top right corner:

[image]

To get around this problem, you can remove the legend title from the `ggplot` object altogether and add the annotation by hand yourself:

```
gg <- ggplot( mtcars, aes( x=mpg, y=wt, color=factor(vs) ) ) +
  geom_point() + theme( legend.title = element_blank() )
ggplotly( gg ) %>%
  add_annotations( text="MyTitle", xref="paper", yref="paper",
                  x=1.02, xanchor="left",
                  y=0.8, yanchor="bottom",    # Same y as legend below
                  legendtitle=TRUE, showarrow=FALSE ) %>%
  layout( legend=list(y=0.8, yanchor="top" ) )
```

Note that the same `y` coordinate is used for both the title and the legend, but the former is anchored at the bottom, while the latter is anchored at the top. This keeps the title from being "disconnected" from the legend. Here's what the final result looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to something like this where [the legend is titled, and the subplot's titles are customized](http://i1.wp.com/dacrook.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Top10MiamiBookings.png)...

Create a trace. In that trace, use the `annotations` attribute to add a name to your legend. I'm able to add pieces of text to my graph wherever I want if I specify an `x` value, a `y` value, and set `xref = 'paper'` and `yref = 'paper'`.

Here is a tutorial on how annotations can be used to your benefit: [Constructing a customized x- and y- axis title](https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/#adding-annotations-with-xref-and-yref-as-paper).

You can read more about [annotations](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-annotations). They are useful!