# How to adjust legend title position in ggplotly in r?

Tags: r, ggplotly

**I have converted the basic `ggplot` into `plotly` graph but unable to move `legend title`.**

1. **Basic ggplot:**

```
cases_ts_India <- df_stack %>% 
  filter(Country.Region == "India") %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Cases_count, col = Cases_type)) +
  geom_path()

cases_ts_India
```

[image]

2. **plotly graph:**

[image]

3. Moved the `legend` but **unable** to move `legend title` and its showing starting part of the title at the old location:

```
ggplotly(cases_ts_India) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", y =-0.2))
```

[image]

I have tried moving title but it didn't work with below lines of code:

```
ggplotly(cases_ts_India) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x =0.2, y = -0.2),
         legend.title = list(orientation = "h", x =0.2, y = -0.2))
```

**Updating Attempt**:

```
cases_ts_India <- cases_ts_India + 
  theme( legend.title = element_blank())
                  
ggplotly(cases_ts_India) %>% 
  layout(title = "India Cases types over the year ",
         legend = list(orientation = "h", x =0.2, y = -0.2)) %>% 
  add_annotations( text="Cases_type",
                  x=0.1, xanchor="left",
                  y=-0.2, yanchor="bottom",    # Same y as legend below
                  legendtitle=TRUE, showarrow=FALSE )
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034308/legend-title-in-plotly ?

Comment: @RonakShah thanks for sharing the link. I have tried a modification of that but it didnt work. Updating the Original post with the code & result

Comment: Please try solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001518/add-title-to-the-plotly-legend)

Comment: thanks @YBS, was able to run it successfully with this !!